# How do I turn number values into an array in Javascript? I want to use array into the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Here I want to use array method `pop`, but I can't because num has a returned integer value. So, How can I turn the value into an array.

```
let num = 0;
for(i=0; i<=10; i++){
    num = i
  let r = num.pop()
  console.log(num, r)
}
```

I am expecting

```
num return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 

& console [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize array by `num = []`.

And `num.pop()` will read and delete element.

Here is a modified code

```
let num = []; 
for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
{ 
    num.push(i)    
    //num[i-1] = i
}   
let r = num.pop();   
console.log(num, r)
```

You could add value to array by `num.push` or `num[i-1]=i` method.

Answer (score 0):

`.pop()` is an array method and it won't work here because your num variable is not an array.
You can solve it by creating another variable of an empty array, and actually populate that one.
Something like this

```
let num_array = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from()` to construct an array of numbers:

```js
const num = Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i) => i + 1);
const r = num.pop();
console.log(JSON.stringify(num), r);
```